#  Where is a Dropdown Menu in Sketchflow

Tags: expression-blend, expression-sketchflow

Ok I cannot freaking can't believe this.  I cannot find a dropdown menu in Sketchflow - Expression Blend 4.  I need to create a mockup quicky and easy and it's amazing how I cannot find a simple dropdown to drag to my project's web page mock-up I am creating here.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF/SL the dropdown is called `ComboBox`

You can search for the `sketch` controls and select the ComboBox from the Assets window, or you can select it from right clicking on the Buttons icon on the toolbar:

[image]